# How can I call an initialization function on a Grails service?

Tags: grails

I have a Grails service that is a wrapper around a rather complicated singleton object. I'd like to do some initializing to populate the singleton when the service is started. It would be nice if there was some kind of init() function that would be automatically called by the service when it starts, but I have found no such thing.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: you mean an actual Service class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can implement `InitializingBean` as described by @Saurabh but that fires rather early in the Grails startup process, so while it works, the are some things that won't be available yet, for example you can't call GORM methods in domain classes because that happens after bean initialization. If `InitializingBean` isn't sufficient you can call an initialization method from `BootStrap.groovy`, e.g.

```
class BootStrap {

   def myService

   def init = { servletContext ->
      myService.initialize()
   }
}
```

and you can call the method `initialize` or whatever you want in the service class. You can also do the initialization work directly in `BootStrap` if you don't want that code in the service class.

Comment: I'll be needing those GORM methods, so I guess this is the best way.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, it make sense to use BootStrap.groovy for initialization.

Comment: Calling from Bootstrap is a fine solution, and allows you to control the order your services initialize. That said, I think the @PostConstruct annotation is less code if you don't need that find grain control.

Comment: It doesn't work on my bootstrap :( tried both ways `@PostConstruct` and  `implements InitializingBean`

Comment: When using the grailsResourceLocator bean in grails 2.5, it is not available in either the @PostConstruct nor the InitializingBean bean. However, the  BootStrap.init() works.

Answer (score 26):

I use the standard PostConstruct annotation:

```
class MyService {    

    @PostConstruct
    def init() {
      // GORM accesible from here
    }

}
```

Comment: Here's a link - http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/08/27/using-postconstruct-annotation-with-grails-services/

Comment: Updated link: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-postconstruct-annotation-with-grails-services/

Comment: worked like charm, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

Server can implement InitializingBean to do some initialization

```
public class AbcService implements InitializingBean {

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    //initialization logic goes here
     }

   }    
}
```

Comment: GORM will not be available InitializingBean..If you want to use Gorm, put initialization logic in  Bootstrap.groovy..

Comment: I need to work on data injected on the bean, no external services so I prefer to have the initialisation logic and "call" inside the same object rather than call it in bootstrap